# Java code - how to remove only annotated methods with script

Tags: java, code-generation, automated-refactoring, transpiler

I wonder if there is a way (a gradle script or any script or any other way without an IDE) to remove methods annotated with certain annotations. Example:

```java
class x {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = getValue();
    System.out.println(x);
  }

  @RemoveEnabled(id = "getValueMethod1", return = "10")
  int getValue() {
    return 20;
  }
}
```

Now when I run the script or gradle target, it should remove the getValue() method, and the output code should become:

```java
class x {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Is there an existing script or way to achieve this? It might be achievable with grep and String parsing etc., but I'm looking for a cleaner solution which is able to get all methods by an annotation id, and remove them with formatting. I tried searching on Google, Stack Overflow etc., but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Would you want this done from inside an IDE, or by a program reading the source code?

Comment: Hi @MauricePerry - Preferably a program or a gradle target.. something which can be independently invoked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a module to process similiar task.

https://github.com/KnIfER/Metaline

```
@StripMethods(keys={"ToRemove","AlsoRemove"})
public class YourCLZ{

void ToRemove(){} // will be removed

void AlsoRemove(){} // will be removed

@StripMethods(strip=true)
void AnotherTest(){} // will also be removed

}
```

in your case

```
@StripMethods(keys="getValue")
class yourx {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = getValue();
    System.out.println(x);
  }

  int getValue() {
    return 20;
  }
}
```

will become:

```
class yourx {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

you will get a compilation error since for now my module simply remove any methods or method body statements that contain the key you specified.